# How to generate 2 list of tuples that are pairwise distinct

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 list of tuples generated from the random library.

In each of the list itself, there are no duplicates. (Using `random.sample()`)

What is the easiest (most pythonic) way to generate the 2 lists such that they are pairwise distinct?

Current code I have:

```
 list1 = list(zip(random.sample(range(1, 100000), 2000), random.sample(range(1, 8000), 2000)))
 list2 = list(zip(random.sample(range(1, 100000), 3000), random.sample(range(1, 8000), 3000)))
```

Example:

```
list1 = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]
list2 = [(1,1), (2,3), (1,3)] # Wrong, because (1,1) is already in list 1

list1 = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]
list2 = [(1,2), (2,3), (1,3)] # Correct, as none of the tuples in list 1 is equal to list 2
```

The tuples in the lists are rows and columns. E.g.: (1,1) means row 1 column 1.
So if (1,1) is already taken up by list1, it should not be taken by list2.

Comment: Do you want to allow a list to have two elements in the same row or column, as long as they don't have both the same row *and* the same column?

Comment: For example, should it be possible for `list1` to contain both `(1, 1)` and `(1, 2)`? (And what about `(1, 1)` being in `list1` and `(1, 2)` being in `list2`?)

Comment: why not make the list twice as long then split it in two?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes, that's what i want

Comment: I think @PatrickParker suggestion is best. Except, instead of twice as long, make a list of length `(len_1 + len_2)` and then slice it with `[:len_1]` and `[len_1:]`,, to get `list_1` and `list_2`, respectively

Comment: if a tuple in list2 exists in list1 then replace it.  This is the rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of generating your lists separately, generate one big list and slice it. However, you also need to fix a bug with your existing list generation.

Your existing list generation does more than prevent duplicates. It prevents a list from containing both `(1, 1)` and `(1, 2)` - rather than ensuring all tuples in the same list are distinct, it makes all first elements distinct and all second elements distinct.

You need to sample from all possible tuples, or equivalently, from a range of integers that you then convert to tuples:

```
max_row = 100000
max_col = 8000

len1 = 2000
len2 = 3000

big_sample = random.sample(range(max_row*max_col), len1+len2)
sample_as_coordinates = [(num // max_col + 1, num % max_col + 1) for num in big_sample]

list1 = sample_as_coordinates[:len1]
list2 = sample_as_coordinates[len1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the lists into sets and take their difference:

```
list1 = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]
list2 = [(1,1), (2,3), (1,3)]

set1 = set(list1).difference(set(list2))
set2 = set(list2).difference(set(list1))

print(list(set1))
print(list(set2))

#prints
#[(3, 3), (2, 2)]
#[(2, 3), (1, 3)]
```

To ensure that the lengths of the original random lists are preserved, the set strategy can be incorporated in a recursive function like this:

```
def create_unique(length1, length2):
    list1 = list(zip(random.sample(range(1, 100000), length1), random.sample(range(1, 8000), length1)))
    list2 = list(zip(random.sample(range(1, 100000), length2), random.sample(range(1, 8000), length2)))

    intersect = set(list1).intersection(set(list2))
    #base case
    if not intersect:
        return list1, list2
    #recursive case
    return create_unique(length1 - len(intersect), length2 - len(intersect))

a = create_unique(2000,3000)

#a is a tuple of two non-overlapping sets of tuples of specified lengths
print(len(a[0])) #2000
print(len(a[1])) #3000
```

Comment: If I do this, than the size of the lists would be incorrect. From length = 3 to length = 2 in your example

Comment: @Kai I understand.  See my amended solution which employs a recursive function to ensure that the lengths of the original lists are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

enumerate the list2 and check items if in list1.  generate an unique tuple not found in list1 and replace the list2 tuple equal to the list1 tuple.  use set to see if the resulting set is unique.  use cross product and counter to see if any combination is non unique.

```
 import random
 from random import sample

 list1 = list(zip(sample(range(1, 100000), 20), sample(range(1, 80000), 20)))
 list2 = list(zip(sample(range(1, 100000), 30), sample(range(1, 80000), 30)))

 for item in list2:
      for index,item2 in enumerate(list1):
           if item==item2:
                replace_tuple=random.choice(range(1, 100000)),random.choice(range(1, 100000))
                while replace_tuple in list1:
                   replace_tuple=random.choice(range(1, 100000)),random.choice(range(1, 100000))
                   list2[index]=replace_tuple

  print("list1 test for uniqueness",len(list1)==len(set(list1)))            
  print("list2 test for uniqueness",len(list2)==len(set(list2)))

  #second test for uniqueness between the two lists

  import itertools
  results=[*itertools.product(list1,list2)]
  #print(results)

  from collections import Counter
  cntr=Counter(results)
  if max(cntr.values())>1:
      print('failed')
  else
      print('no duplicates')
```